# Can't get css with @media print to work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am trying to make it so that when I try to print my page, the only thing that is printed is 1 long single div from that page.

After some research I figured out how to limit the browser to only print certain elements by using @media print, and setting visibility to hidden for the elements I do not want to show.

This is the css that I currently am using to accomplish this:

```
@media print {
html, body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
body * {
    visibility: hidden;
}

table {
    float: none !important;
}
div {
    float: none !important;
}


#PermitDetails, #PermitDetails * {
    visibility: visible;
}

#PermitDetails {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
}
```

This code allows the PermitDetails div to display when printing, and hides any other elements (and the scrollbar) while printing.

This is the code for the PermitDetails div:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-10">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="PermitDetailsPanel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Permit Details</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id="PermitDetails">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This div is dynamically filled in based on options that the user selects on the page, so the size of it is always different.

The problem that I am having with this is that if I try to print the page, I do see only the div with the proper information, however there are a couple of things that are wrong:

1. Even though I have the div's position set as absolute, and left and top to 0, it still positions itself in the center of the page. I also noticed that it moves up or down based on where in the page I am currently scrolling to.
2. If I select enough information that the div fills up the page, the information does not move onto a second page to print. It just fills up the first page and gets cut off once it hits the bottom. This also moves around based on where I am scrolling on the page.

I read that this could be due to how bootstrap floats the columns, so I tried setting the div tags to float:none in the css (as seen above), but that did not change anything.

I'm really not sure what else the problem could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Have you tried using `display: none` instead of `visibility: hidden` to hide the content, and then you probably don't need to use `position: absolute` on `#PermitDetails`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Doesn't `display: none` also hide the children of whatever I apply it to? I think I tried that already, and also tried setting the display of `#PermitDetails` to something else and still had issues because of this.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see your HTML structure. What if you added `.permitParent` to the ancestors of the "permit" elements, and set `*:not(.permitParent) { display: none; }`? I might just try that as a troubleshooting step to see if it's a problem with how the print stylesheet handles elements hidden with `visibility: hidden` vs `display: none`

Comment: @MichaelCoker That doesn't seem to work either. It seems like `display:none` will hide the child elements even if they are set differently.